# Adding Disclosure Buttons to a Table when using Data.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, button, disclosure

I've created a table from a data.plist and was trying to figure out how to add a disclosure button at the second level-to-third level table.  It would be used to add a UIView "credits" to the student artists who made the picture.  However, I need to make sure that the name can change as the table will house different files from different students.  So for example, cases 1-3 would all be Aubrey's work, and cases 4-6 would be Josh's, etc.

Any help would be great.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DrillDownAppAppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize tableDataSource, CurrentTitle, CurrentLevel;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(CurrentLevel == 0) {

        //Initialize our table data source
        NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
        [tempArray release];

        DrillDownAppAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (DrillDownAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Rows"];

        self.navigationItem.title = @"Electromagnetism";
    }
    else 
        self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;   
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.tableDataSource count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Get the children of the present item.
    NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

    if([Children count] == 0) {
        NSInteger ViewNumber = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"View"] integerValue];
        switch (ViewNumber) {
            case 1: {

                ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                ivc.ImageName = @"Magnets_History_Aubrey.jpg";
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
                [ivc release];              
            }
                break;              
            case 2: {
                ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                ivc.ImageName = @"Magnets_Theory_Aubrey.jpg";
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
                [ivc release];
            }
                break;
            case 3: {
                ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                ivc.ImageName = @"Magnets_AU_Aubrey.jpg";
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
                [ivc release];
            }
                break;
            default: {
                DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
                [dvController release];
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    else {

        //Prepare to tableview.
        RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        //Increment the Current View
        rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

        //Set the title;
        rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

        //Push the new table view on the stack
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

        rvController.tableDataSource = Children;

        [rvController release];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tbController release];
    [CurrentTitle release];
    [tableDataSource release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to indicate a disclosure in the cell you can make use of the property `accessoryType`.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Which can have any of these

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,                   // don't show any accessory view
    UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,    // regular chevron. doesn't track
    UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton, // blue button w/ chevron. tracks
    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark               // checkmark. doesn't track
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

Comment: Thanks 7KV7.  I got the Blue button to chevron to work by adding it to - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
, however it is also showing up on the first level.  How would I get that to change or remove on the code above?

Comment: If you dont want to show do this cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

Comment: Well, that's half of my problem.  So I generate a table using a data.plist.  There's essentially three tiers.  At the first tier, it goes to three second level tiers.  The first level tiers do not need the disclosure button.  Only the second level tier does.

Comment: yes you can provide the above codes based on your tiers. According to the tiers, specify the accessoryType

Comment: I'm still confused on where to add it because all levels have the button.  I just want the second level.